# Redirection issue with yii, AWS and wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, nginx, yii

I have a site in yii framework with that I want to setup my blog. My site setup is on xyz.com and I want to setup blog at xyz.com/blog. When I install wordpress in my root folder of yii I am redirected to elb url of AWS. We are using cloud front on main site. We tried defining WP_SITEURL in wp-config but that gives redirection loop issue so we tried multi site setup that stopped showing anything on site but downloads a file having content of header.php.

nginx settings are given below :

```
    location /wordpress/ {
        rewrite ^/wordpress/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ /wordpress/$1wp-admin/ redirect;
        if (-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/wordpress/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /wordpress/$2 break;
        }
        rewrite ^/wordpress/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ /wordpress/$2 break;
        rewrite ^/wordpress/(.*)$ /wordpress/index.php break;
    }
```

I am able to check admin that is also on elb url only not on actual site url.

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried install WordPress in "blog" directory in web root of xyz.com?

You have yii web root directory with index.php file. So in this directory you should create folder "blog" and extract wordpress archive to her.

It should be seems like bellow:

- assets
- blog
- - wp-content
- - index.php (Wordpress bootstrap)
- images
- protected
- index.php (Yii bootstrap file)